# Get an attribute of a page element in pupeeter/apify

Tags: puppeteer, apify

I could fetch the *textContent* of a html element in pupeeter:

```
var website_element = await page.$('a[itemprop="url"]');
var website= await (await website_element .getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();
```

yet, sometimes the *textContent* is not enough, see the following html:

```
<a itemprop="url" href="https://www.4-b.ch/de/4b-fenster-fassaden/home/">
https://www.4-b.ch/de/4b-fenster-fassad...</a>
```

the result is obscure: "**https://www.4-b.ch/de/4b-fenster-fassad...**" with **...** at the end.

So, i better get the **href** attribute.

But when:

```
var website_element = await page.$('a[itemprop="url"]');
var website = await (await website_element.getAttribute('href')).jsonValue();
```

The result is **TypeError: website_element.getAttribute is not a function**

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy and fast way to do this using the [page.$eval](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) function:

```js
var website = await page.$eval('a[itemprop="url"]', el => el.href);
```

What `page.$eval` does is that it first finds an element in the DOM using the provided selector (first argument) and then invokes the callback (second argument) with the found element as its only argument. The return value of the callback becomes the return value of `page.$eval()` itself.

Answer (score 0):

it works:

```
var website_element = await page.$('a[itemprop="url"]');
var website = await (await website_element.getProperty('href')).jsonValue();
```